# fs.writeFile is not a function Electron/React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm trying to write a little proof of concept app with React and Electron, following the tutorial here:

https://medium.com/@brockhoff/using-electron-with-react-the-basics-e93f9761f86f

I have one button called "Save me!" in the App component. I wrote the handler to print out "Hello World" to console, which worked, so I know the handler is not the problem. In memory, I have a simple object:

```
var json = {
    "foo":"bar",
    "bar":"none"
}
```

In the handler is a typical function to write the contents of `json` to a file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("temp.txt", json, (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
});
```

However, when I press on the button, the console spits out an error message stating that `fs.writeFile` is not a function. Any help here?

Edit:
Why is this question marked as duplicate, when the a post in the "duplicate" question literally says:

> Also take a look at https://electronjs.org/ It allows you to use
>   nodejs APIs like fs in you "native"-like react app.

How is this a duplicate question when the addition of Electron clearly seems to be a significant difference between the two?

Edit 2: For clarification, `fs` **does** work on Electron. I had to invoke it in a somewhat weird way:

```
var app = window.require('electron').remote;
const fs = app.require('fs');
```

For anyone who is having trouble with `window.require`, use `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` to reinstall your node modules

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300

Problem solved.

Comment: FS doesn't work on client-side (browser)

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron - no, that is not correct. Node works fine on the client side.

Comment: @NoGrabbing, Yeah node, not fs.

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron - fs is **part** of node – I use it all the time on the client side in Electron.

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron A post in the "duplicate" question linked clearly says that `fs` is allowed in Electron. Why mark a question as a duplicate when there's clearly some contradiction/confusion

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron I solved the problem myself and verified that `fs` does work in Electron.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding and glad you resolved your problem.